# How to replace a string in a table with a null value using kdb

Tags: string, null, tabs, kdb

I have 1 table in the form as follows:

[image]

I want to set c2 to "" when c1>2, expect the result to be like this:

[image]

I try to do:

```
t:([] c1:1 2 3 4;c2:("abcd";"efgh";"igkl";"mnop"))
c:enlist (>; `c1; 2)
b:0b;
a:(enlist `c2)!enlist "";
![t;c;b;a]
```

But it reported an error: length: Incompatible list lengths
Please tell me what to do,thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `c2` is a list of chars (IE a string) you need to `enlist` "" first & then take (`#`) the number of strings you need. In this case I've used `count[i]`.

```
q)update c2:count[i]#enlist"" from t where c1>2
c1 c2
---------
1  "abcd"
2  "efgh"
3  ""
4  ""
```

In functional form:

```
q)parse"update c2:count[i]#enlist\"\"from t where c1>2"
!
`t
,,(>;`c1;2)
0b
(,`c2)!,(#;(#:;`i);(enlist;""))
q)![t;enlist(>;`c1;2);0b;enlist[`c2]!enlist(#;(count;`i);(enlist;""))]
c1 c2
---------
1  "abcd"
2  "efgh"
3  ""
4  ""
```

Comment: Using `i` generates a list `0 1 ... N-1` which has a cost so if you want to be as efficient as possible use an existing column `q)update c2:count[c2]#enlist"" ...`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using the `@` operator:

```
t[`c2]:@[t[`c2];where 2<t`c1;{""}]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
c1 c2
---------
1  "abcd"
2  "efgh"
3  ""
4  ""
```

This is slighly faster than the `update` solution:

```
q)\t:1000000 @[t[`c2];where 2<t[`c1];{""}]
1054
q)\t:1000000 update c2:count[i]#enlist"" from t where c1>2
1237
```